# Javascript doesnt work when using data-page-list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

```
   function editTrigger() {
    $("tbody td:not(.unclickable)").on("click", function (event) {

        var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        id = id.substr(2, id.length);
        window.location = "@Url.Action("Edit")" + "/" + id;
    });
}
```

hello, 
i've this javascript trigger to action redirect to the edit view in my MVC index. 
So the problem is, when i use:

```
table class="tablesModel"
       data-search="true"
       data-mobile-responsive="true"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, All]">
```

and change pages, the trigger doenst work anymore. 
what can i do ?

Comment: I'm not able to say anything specific without seeing more code, but `"@Url.Action("Edit")"` looks wrong. Change the double quotes around `Edit` to single quotes and see if it does anything. At its current state, it should most certainly throw an error. Or change the Double quotes in the string except `"Edit"` into single quotes.

Comment: @YousofK. I believe that only looks wrong because of some hiccups with SO's syntax highlighting. `@Url.Action("Edit")` would be replaced server-side and rendered as a URL, so the JavaScript would never know that `@Url.Action("Edit")` was even there.